# Gmail reports illegal attachment without any attachments

Tags: django, email, gmail, email-attachments, sendgrid

We use Django and then Sendgrid to send and deliver transactional e-mails to our users. Since a few weeks back Gmail has increasingly started bouncing the email with the following reason:

```
552 5.7.0 Our system detected an illegal attachment on your message. Please visit http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6590 to review our attachment guidelines. ux5si5383759icb.101
```

The weird thing is that our email is a simple short text message without any attachments that we know of. The emails usually arrive just fine, but this is happening more often.

Where should we look for the cause? Could we be messing with the e-mail headers, encodings etc that cause Gmail to react like this? Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: If you send the email to a non-gmail address, does it deliver? What's the raw envelope/headers?

Answer (score 0):

We've been experiencing a dramatic increase in this recently, too.  Our messages to recipients who use Google's email systems do include attachments, but these are clean pdf's. Sometimes the messages arrive but the attachments can't be opened ("damaged"), sometimes they bounce back with the "illegal attachment" bounce message.  I'm seeing this issue reported by many people, going back years, but I have yet to find a single authoritative reponse from Google, or any real fix.  Our messages go out from our Exchange 2003 server, and I'm wondering if that's relevant.

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer.